# NASM: parser: instruction expected rep movs

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I've been turning an executable into some NASM shellcode (for windows if it's relevant) but i'm encountering "error: parser: instruction expected" errors all over the place from rep instructions.

```
label_0000641:
lea    edi,[esp+0x164]                      
label_0000648:
rep movs DWORD es:[edi],DWORD ds:[esi]
label_000064a:
and    DWORD [esp+0x168],0x0
```

Is there some special nasm syntax for this? Am I making a stupid mistake?
I have no idea how to go about fixing these errors and would really like some guidance.

(I'm compiling with nasm -f bin -o out.bin test.asm)

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Convert Instruction in assembly code lods and stos so NASM can compile](//stackoverflow.com/q/40092145) same thing

Answer (score 8):

NASM will not accept `rep movs DWORD es:[edi],DWORD ds:[esi]`

From the [NASM Manual; 2.2.3 NASM Doesn't Store Variable Types](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html)

> NASM, by design, chooses not to remember the types of variables you declare. Whereas MASM will remember, on seeing `var dw 0`, that you declared var as a word-size variable, and will then be able to fill in the ambiguity in the size of the instruction `mov var,2`, NASM will deliberately remember nothing about the symbol var except where it begins, and so you must explicitly code `mov word [var],2`.
>
> For this reason, NASM doesn't support the `LODS`, `MOVS`, `STOS`, `SCAS`, `CMPS`, `INS`, or `OUTS` instructions, but only supports the forms such as `LODSB`, `MOVSW`, and `SCASD`, which explicitly specify the size of the components of the strings being manipulated.

Thus the code to use is `rep movsd`

Answer (score 1):

That just looks like some overly verbose outout from a disassembler.

Quoting from [Intel's manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) (the section named *String Instructions*):

> By default, the `ESI` register addresses the segment identified with the `DS` segment register. ... The `EDI` register
>   addresses the segment identified with the `ES` segment register.
>   ...
>   The `MOVS` instruction moves the string element addressed by the `ESI` register to the location addressed by the `EDI` register. The assembler recognizes three “short forms” of this instruction, which specify the size of the string to be
>   moved: `MOVSB` (move byte string), `MOVSW` (move word string), and `MOVSD` (move doubleword string).

So if we apply that information we end up with:

```
; DWORD operands means movsd, ds:[esi] is the default source, and
; es:[edi] is the default destination
rep movsd
```

---

Note: in the description for `MOVS` in Intel's manual, `MOVS m32, m32` is listed as supported. They call this the *“explicit-operands” form* of the instruction. It only serves a documentational purpose, since the only allowed source is `[(R|E)SI]` and the only allowed destination is `[(R|E)DI]`. I don't know whether or not NASM supports the explicit-operands form, or what the syntax for it is in that case.

Comment: It doesn't, according to [a recent duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092145/convert-instruction-in-assembly-code-lods-and-stos-so-nasm-can-compile).  With a32/a16 mnemonic prefixes, there's no need for it.  GNU `.intel_syntax` does support explicit operands, though (and warns you if you use the wrong register).

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure to initialize `ECX` to string length for `rep` instruction, initialize `EDI` and `ESI` to destination and source string respectively, make sure direction flag is set accordingly then:

```
label_0000641:
lea    edi,[esp+0x164] ;initializing destination?                   
label_0000648:
rep movsd
label_000064a:
and    DWORD [esp+0x168],0x0
```