# Convert Instruction in assembly code lods and stos so NASM can compile

Tags: assembly, nasm

Ok so I am trying to assemble some code in assembly using `nasm -f elf final.asm`:

```
xor eax,eax
push eax
push dword(0x75792273)
push dword(0x70742027)
push dword(0x77777875)
push dword(0x20237678)
push dword(0x76727827)
push dword(0x27797175)
push dword(0x75711225)
push dword(0x72747676)
push dword(0x74231476)
push dword(0x70707470)
push dword(0x23247077)
push dword(0x78707822)
push dword(0x24711174)
push dword(0x22707373)
push dword(0x78717974)
push dword(0x75771777)
push dword(0x70777125)
push dword(0x73731472)
push dword(0x71277377)
push dword(0x79251822)
push dword(0x79707478)
push dword(0x78742779)
push dword(0x72727871)
push dword(0x71251475)
push dword(0x27247772)
push dword(0x79757479)
push dword(0x70227071)
push dword(0x77737420)
push dword(0x70251970)
push dword(0x74747127)
push dword(0x23277677)
push dword(0x79712024)
push esp
pop esi
mov edi,esi
mov edx,edi
cld
mov ecx,0x80
mov ebx,0x41
xor eax,eax
push eax
lods byte[esi]
xor eax,ebx
stos byte[es:edi]
loop 0xb7
push esp
pop esi
int 0x3
```

Which results in the following error:

```
final.asm:44: error: parser: instruction expected
final.asm:46: error: parser: instruction expected
```

I found the answer to these errors at:
[NASM: parser: instruction expected rep movs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364332/nasm-parser-instruction-expected-rep-movs)

Basically, this says that the lods and stos instructions are not recognized by NASM. Which means I need to convert them into something NASM does recognize so that I get the same result.

My question is, what can I change these two lines to so that NASM can compile it so that I can ultimately debug it.

Comment: Change to simply `lodsb` and `stosb` (no operands).

Comment: when I run that, I get: test.asm:44: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
test.asm:46: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

Comment: lodsb byte[esi]
stosb byte[es:edi]

Comment: Just use `lodsb` and `stosb` **not** `lodsb byte [esi]`.

Comment: You are using operands to try to tell the assembler to do what `lodsb` and `stosb` do anyway. For example, `stosb` stores a byte at the address in `edi` using the `es` segment, so you don't have to tell it that.

Comment: That worked!. Though I dont understand why necessary. New to assembly.

Comment: Haha and now you explained why. great thanks a bunch!

Comment: BTW to override segment usage with `lodsb` the syntax in NASM is `ss lodsb` (I was curious myself, as I didn't needed it yet, so I had to search a while to find NASM syntax). `stos` family of instructions is fixed to `es` and can't be overridden.

Comment: Related: [NASM: parser: instruction expected rep movs](//stackoverflow.com/q/31364332)

Comment: @Ped7g: It is true that `stos` instructions are fixed to `es`. However, for completeness's sake, I'd like to add that in all string instructions in which `es` is used as the default it cannot be overridden, but in all of them in which `ds` is used as the default it can be overridden. Particularly: `scas` and `stos` and `ins` always use `es`, `lods` and `outs` default to `ds` but can be overridden, and `cmps` and `movs` use the fixed `es` segment for the `di` operand but use the default `ds` for the `si` operand (which can be overridden without affecting the use of `es`).

Answer (score 5):

what `lodsb` does is:

```
mov al,[esi]
inc esi           ; (or dec, according to direction flag)
```

you could also use
`lodsw` to load words (to `ax`, increase `esi` by 2), or
`lodsd` to load dwords (to `eax`, increase `esi` by 4).

and `stosb` does

```
mov [es:edi],al
inc edi
```

same here, `stosw` and `stosd` will store 2 or 4 bytes (and adjusting `edi` accordingly)

First loads from memory, pointed to by the SOURCE (ESI) register, latter writes to memory pointed by the DESTINATION (ES:EDI) register.

You don't need to (*and cannot*) specify which registers will be used. Source will always be E**S**I, and Destination always E**D**I

---

Edit on segment registers:
The `lods` instruction can be used together with segment override prefix (i.e. `ss lodsb`). The `stos` instruction is fixed to `es` (missing detail in original answer) segment usage, and can't be overridden.

The `movsb/movsw/movsd` instructions (`size*(mov [es:edi],[ds:esi]  inc esi  inc edi)`) can be also overridden on the source side, ie. `es movsb` will fetch bytes from `es:esi` instead of `ds:esi`, but the destination segment register is fixed to `es`.

Comment: @Ped7g of course, register used is `al` ... not `ah` ! thx for correcting

Answer (score 3):

Use `lodsb` / `lodsw` / `lodsd` / `lodsq` to indicate operand-size with the mnemonic itself, *not* with operands.

**Remove the `byte [esi]` part, NASM won't accept explicit operands for string instructions.**

---

[Intel's LODS documentation](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LODS:LODSB:LODSW:LODSD:LODSQ.html) suggests that you can use operands as documentation and to imply an operand-size (and segment override), like you're trying to do, as an alternative to an operand-size suffix.

> This explicit-operands form is provided to allow documentation; however, note that the documentation provided by this form can be misleading. That is, the source operand symbol must specify the correct **type** (size) of the operand (byte, word, or doubleword), but it does not have to specify the correct **location**. The location is always specified by the DS:(E)SI registers, which must be loaded correctly before the load string instruction is executed.

Presumably the designers of NASM syntax decided that allowing `lods byte [r15]` to assemble was a bad idea, and disallowing the one-operand form entirely was easier than writing a bunch of code just to check that the given operand is what it's supposed to be.

Since NASM has a prefix syntax for segment/operand/address overrides, `fs lodsb` lets you write what would otherwise need an operand to attach a segment override to (like `lodsb fs:[rsi]` in MASM syntax.)

Doing it this way makes the string instructions non-special as far as the assembler is concerned; they're just another entry in a table mapping mnemonics to opcodes.  If Intel's own syntax included mnemonic prefixes for machine-code prefix bytes, they might have made the same design choice.

Fun fact: [STOS](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/STOS:STOSB:STOSW:STOSD:STOSQ.html)'s segment can't be overridden (from ES).  Perhaps Intel wanted to share more transistors with the original 8086 implementation of [MOVS](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVS:MOVSB:MOVSW:MOVSD:MOVSQ.html), where a segment override only affects the `[DS:SI]` source, not the `[ES:DI]` destination.

---

**other assemblers**:

GNU `.intel_syntax` supports segment prefix syntax, but not NASM's `o16`/`o32`/`o64` or `a16`/`a32`/`a64` operand and address-size specifiers.

```
# assembled with as --32    disassembled with ndisasm -b 32
.intel_syntax noprefix

    mov    al, byte ptr fs:[esi]
                    00000038  648A06            mov al,[fs:esi]

    gs lodsb
                    0000003B  65AC              gs lodsb
    lods   dword ptr ss:[ecx]
    # Warning: `dword ptr ss:[ecx]' is not valid here (expected `[esi]')
                    0000003D  36AD              ss lodsd
    ss lodsd   [si]
                    0000003F  3667AD            ss a16 lodsd
    lods   eax, dword ptr ss:[esi]
                    00000042  36AD              ss lodsd

#lods al      # Error: operand type mismatch for `lods'
#fs es lodsd  # Error: same type of prefix used twice
#a16 lodsb    # Error: no such instruction: `a16 lodsb'
```

I don't see a way to write an address-size override without using an explicit operand for string instructions in GNU syntax (AT&T or Intel).

`objdump -Mintel` output of the same:

```
   4:   64 8a 06                mov    al,BYTE PTR fs:[esi]
   7:   65 ac                   lods   al,BYTE PTR gs:[esi]
   9:   36 ad                   lods   eax,DWORD PTR ss:[esi]
   b:   36 67 ad                lods   eax,DWORD PTR ss:[si]
   e:   36 ad                   lods   eax,DWORD PTR ss:[esi]
```