# Moving a value of a lesser size into a register

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, zero-extension

I have stored a one-byte value of `8` and I'd like to move that into the `rax` register. I'm currently doing this with `movzx` to zero-extend the byte:

```
.globl main
main:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    movb $8, -1(%rbp)
    movzx -1(%rbp), %rax <-- here
    ...
```

How does the `movzx` instruction 'know' that the value at `-1(%rbp)` is only one byte long? From here is says, if I'm reading it properly, that it can work on both a `byte` and a `word`, but how would it know? For example, if I added a two-byte value at `-2(%rbp)` how would it know to grab the two-byte value? Is there another instruction where I can just grab a `one` or `two` or `four` byte value at an address and insert it into a 64 bit register?

I suppose another way to do it would be to first zero-out the register and then add it to the 8-bit (or however many bits) component, such as:

```
mov $0, %rax
mov -1(%rbp), %al
```

Is there one way that is more preferred than another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does the `movzx` instruction 'know' that the value at `-1(%rbp)` is only one byte long?

There are two (or even three) instructions:

`movzxb` (`-1(%rbp)` is one byte long) and `movzxw` (`-1(%rbp)` is one 16-bit word long).

My assembler interprets `movzx` as `movzxb`; however, you should not rely on that!

Better use the instruction name including the source size (`movzxb` or `movzxw`) to ensure that the assembler uses the correct instruction.

Comment: great, thank you for the clarification. Is there a third instruction that is 32 bits long?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 For the `movsx` instruction there is `movsxl` that uses a 32-bit source. `movzxl` **seems** not to exist because any operation writing to the `%eax` register will implicitly set the high 32 bits of `%rax` to zero. So you can simply do a `mov -1(%rbp), %eax` instruction.

Comment: `movzxb` is a mutant hybrid of Intel and AT&T syntax.  I wouldn't recommend it, compilers never use it and I've never seen it mentioned anywhere.  It does apparently work as equivalent to standard AT&T `movzb`, though.  I was surprised, I expected it to be a destination size override for `movzx` and fail.  (Possibly I'm totally  mistaken and this is documented or standardized somewhere, but I've never seen it.)

Comment: Note that the standard AT&T mnemonics for these are `movzbl` and `movzwl`.  It's always `movzXY` for a zero-extending move from size X to size Y and `movsXY` for a sign extending move.

Answer (score 4):

It's ambiguous and relies on some default, you shouldn't write code like that.

That's why AT&T syntax has `movzb` and `movzw` instructions (typically used as `movzbl -1(%rbp), %eax`), for the two different source sizes of the Intel-syntax `movzx` mnemonic.  See [Are x86 Assembly Mnemonic standarized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54369684/are-x86-assembly-mnemonic-standarized) (no, AT&T makes up new names.)

And yes, you *could* `xor %eax,%eax` / `mov -1(%rbp), %al` to merge into the low byte, but that's pointlessly inefficient.  x86-64 guarantees the availability of 386 instructions like movzx.

Surprisingly, `movzx -1(%rbp), %rax` does assemble.  If you assemble it, then disassemble back into AT&T syntax with `objdump -d foo.o`, you get `movzbq` (byte to quad), including a useless REX prefix instead of letting [implicit zero-extension do the job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6) after writing EAX.

```
48 0f b6 45 ff          movzbq -0x1(%rbp),%rax
```

Or disassemble into Intel syntax with `objdump -drwC -Mintel`:

```
48 0f b6 45 ff          movzx  rax,BYTE PTR [rbp-0x1]
```

---

Fun fact: GAS can't infer `movzb` vs. `movzw` if you write just `movz`, because `movz` isn't an instruction mnemonic.  Unlike operand-size suffixes that can be inferred from the operands, the `b` and `w` are treated as part of the mnemonic.  But you can write `movzx` and then it will infer both sizes from register operands, just like in Intel-syntax mode.

```
   5:   0f b6 c0                movzbl %al,%eax         # source: movzx %al, %eax
   8:   0f b7 c0                movzwl %ax,%eax         # source: movzx %ax, %eax
```

`movzw` and `movzb` act like instruction mnemonics in their own right (that can infer a size suffix from the destination register).  Semi-related:  [What does the MOVZBL instruction do in IA-32 AT&T syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317922/what-does-the-movzbl-instruction-do-in-ia-32-att-syntax/31115069#31115069)

Also related: a table of cdq and so on equivalents in terms of `movsx` and AT&T equivalents: [What does cltq do in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555094/what-does-cltq-do-in-assembly/45386217#45386217)

Also related: [MOVZX missing 32 bit register to 64 bit register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51387571/movzx-missing-32-bit-register-to-64-bit-register) - because that's implicit in writing a 32-bit register.