# Accessing array elements using indexed addressing

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-64, att, addressing-mode

What is the proper way to access array elements in x86_64? For example, here is what I have going so far:

```
my_array:   .word 20,25,30,35
.globl _start
_start:

    movq $0, %rdi                  # should we use rdi for the offset?
    movz my_array(,%rdi,2), $r13   # how to move two bytes in r13 and zero-pad the rest?
    add $6, %rdi                   # move to next index position for my_array[3]
    movz my_array(,%rdi,2), $r14   # how to move two bytes in r14 and zero-pad the rest?
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is the following in pseudocode:

```
%r13 = my_array[0] # (20)
%r14 = my_array[3] # (35)
```

This is pretty sloppy and I'm sure the wrong way to do it (not to mention the `movz` is mis-sized and I'm having trouble figuring that out. What would be the correct way to do this then, using indexed-addressing mode?

Comment: Never use `movz` without a source operand size like `movzw`.  Also, `$r14` is not a register name and will fail to assemble, I think you mean `%r14`.  Also, the `add` instruction is unnecessary, use `my_array+6(,%rdi,2)` if you have a known constant offset.  (Or better, just `my_array(%rip)` and `my_array+6(%rip)` for both known constant indexes).

Comment: If you want examples, compile a C function that takes an arg and uses it to index a global array, returning the value.  Look at the asm output.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the feedback. I did that on godbolt but they're not using indexed addressing for the array, which I'm trying to learn: https://godbolt.org/z/jv5MoP. They just keep adding the array elements one at a time.

Comment: @PeterCordes also, for the `movz`, what part of the command is optional and which part isn't, for example, I see results such as: `movzbw, movzbl, movzbq, movzwl, movzwq`. And wasn't sure if `movz` or `movzb` or `movzbw` is the right way to do it.

Comment: Read my comment more carefully, and read the linked answer: a function *that takes an arg* and uses it to index the array.  You just wrote a `main` where everything is a compile-time constant, so of course the compiler isn't going to put a `0` in a register and index with it.

Comment: @PeterCordes oh I see, thanks for pointing that out. Ok I got something that shows that now on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/KKbqr6.

Comment: Way more readable if you use `-Og` to optimize *some*, but still without function inlining: 
 https://godbolt.org/z/nrfr5x.  You also don't need the `main` caller, you're not going to run it, just look at the asm output.  (With no caller, you can crank up the optimization level to full `-O3` to see if anything changes.  Or still look at the stand-alone definition which still exists because the function isn't `static` or `inline`.)

Comment: re: movzx in AT&T syntax: see [Moving a value of a lesser size into a register](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63389435).  The accepted answer on that question uses `movzxb`; don't do that, that's a voodoo hybrid of AT&T and Intel mnemonics.  See also [What does the MOVZBL instruction do in IA-32 AT&T syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31115069) which should have been the first hit if you googled for `site:stackoverflow.com movzbl`